# "and been" vs "and has been" when "has" is repeated.

Tags: grammaticality, auxiliary-verbs, redundancy

I have the sentence:

> The role has gotten easier and easier to play, **and been** forced upon me more frequently than not.

I was wondering if **and been** is correct to use in this case, or if "has" must be used again i.e. **and been** or **and has been**.

Comment: Both would be correct

Comment: I think the question that you are trying to ask is: Can you omit the 'has' in the present perfect when using it multiple times in a sentence (i.e. after a conjunction)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - The role has gotten easier and easier to play, and been forced upon me more frequently than not.

In this sentence, *has* is an auxiliary verb used in a present perfect construction. *Gotten* is the past participle of the lexical verb *get*. (In British English the past participle of this verb is *got*, but *become* would be more natural in this particular sentence.)

We could indicate the structure of the sentence thus:

- The role has [gotten easier and easier to play] and [been forced upon me more frequently than not]

The bracketed sections there are coordinates linked by the co-ordinator *and*. They are also both dependents of the auxiliary verb *has*.

Because both of the conjuncts are verb phrases which are dependents of the the same auxiliary, there is no need to repeat the auxiliary verb here. The sentence is perfectly grammatical.

Comment: IMHO closely related to the above question: In cases where the past participle would be repeated ("sth has not [been tested] or even [been deployed] ...")–can you choose to omit or are you even expected to omit the second occurrence ("sth has not [been tested] or even [deployed] ...")?